# How can I use the "with" command correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a query and it works, by which I get the category subsets.

```
with cte as (
    Select nid 
    from TB_Category 
    where nid = 429
    union ALL
    select ca.nid 
    from cte ct 
    inner join TB_Category ca on ca.parentid = ct.nid
)
SELECT p.nid 
from TB_Category p 
inner join cte ct on ct.nid = p.nid
```

**To delete the selected categories I use the following command but it gives an error:**

```
DELETE FROM TB_Category 
WHERE nid in (
    with cte as (
        Select nid 
        from TB_Category 
        where nid = 429
        union ALL
        select ca.nid 
        from cte ct 
        inner join TB_Category ca on ca.parentid = ct.nid
    )
    SELECT p.nid 
    from TB_Category p 
    inner join cte ct on ct.nid = p.nid
)
```

**Displays the following error:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
> common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
> context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
> semicolon.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
> common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
> context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
> semicolon.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You probably want a cascading foreign key constraint rather than a `delete` with a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete by using a join:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT nid 
   FROM TB_Category 
   WHERE nid= 429
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ca.nid 
   FROM cte ct 
   INNER JOIN TB_Category ca ON ca.parentid = ct.nid
)
DELETE t
FROM TB_Category t
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.nid = t.nid
```

But be aware, that if you have a real constraint between nid and parentid, the deletion won't work that simple - you might experience constraint violations if the deletion tries to process the parent record before the child record.

Answer (score 3):

Use CTE at start of the query as follows:

```
with cte as (
    Select nid 
    from TB_Category 
    where nid = 429
    union ALL
    select ca.nid 
    from cte ct 
    inner join TB_Category ca on ca.parentid = ct.nid
)    
DELETE
FROM TB_Category 
WHERE nid in (
    SELECT p.nid 
    from TB_Category p 
    inner join cte ct on ct.nid = p.nid
)
```